# pandoc: render supscript with html tags

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'm converting a docx document to markdon. The markdown file will be used as a README file on a github repository:

`pandoc -s manuscript.docx -t markdown -o README.md`

Is there a way to tell pandoc to render the superscript with html tags ?
I would pandoc to output:

`<sup>a_number</sup>`

Instead of:

`^a_number^`

Comment: You'll need a filter: http://pandoc.org/scripting.html#json-filters that transforms superscripts elements into rawinline elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending on scoa's comment, you just need to replace the Superscript elements with equivalent RawInline elements. [This](https://github.com/sergiocorreia/panflute-filters/blob/master/filters/html_superscript.py) filter does it for you (requires python 3.3+ and the panflute package (`pip install panflute`).

```
import panflute as pf


def action(elem, doc):
    if isinstance(elem, pf.Superscript) and doc.format == 'markdown':
        text = '<sup>' + pf.stringify(elem) + '</sup>'
        return pf.RawInline(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pf.run_filter(action)
```

Example usage:

```
>> echo 2^10^ is 1024 | pandoc --to=markdown -F html_superscript.py
2<sup>10</sup> is 1024
```